# problem with regular expressions php

Tags: php, regex

```
/any_string/any_string/any_number
```

with this regular expression:

```
/(\w+).(\w+).(\d+)/
```

It works, but I need this url:

```
/specific_string/any_string/any_string/any_number
```

And I don't know how to get it.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *i need this url*? Does your expression not match with the second URL? Btw. your expression should include `/` instead of *any character `.`*, e.g. by changing the delimiter: `~(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)~`. Also note that `\w+` does not match *any string* but *any word character string*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(specific_string).(\w+).(\w+).(\d+)/`

Though note that the `.`s in your regular expression technically match **any** character and 
not just the `/`

`/(specific_string)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+)/`

This will have it match only slashes.

Answer (score 0):

This one will match the second url:

```
"/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+)/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\/specific_string\/(\w+).(\w+).(\d+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the specific_string in the regexp:

```
/specific_string\/(\w+)/(\w+)/\d+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant with the outer delimiters changed to avoid extraneous escaping:

```
preg_match("#/FIXED_STRING/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)#", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
"/\/specific_string\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(\d+)/"
```

I use `[^\/]+` because that will match anything that is not a slash. `\w+` will work almost all the time, but this will also work if there is an unexpected character in the path somewhere. Also note that my regex requires the leading slash.

If you want to get a little more complicated, the following regex will match **both** of the patterns you provided:

```
"/^(?:\/specific_string)*\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(\d+)$/"
```

This will match:

```
"/any_string/any_string/any_number"
"/specific_string/any_string/any_string/any_number"
```

but it will **not** match

```
"/some_other_string/any_string/any_string/any_number"
```